# webpacker compiling but not saving file in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I am working on a project using rails and react Am using webpacker. I get this message:

> Processing by CurrenciesController#index as HTML
>     Rendering currencies/index.html.erb within layouts/application
>   [Webpacker] Compiling…
>   [Webpacker] Compiled all packs in C:/Users/omokehinde/Documents/RailsProjects/cryptoCalculator/public/packs
>     Rendered currencies/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9526.0ms)
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9955ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>   ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find hello_react.js in C:/Users/omokehinde/Documents/RailsProjects/cryptoCalculator/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
>   1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
>      unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
>   2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
>   3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
>   4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
>   Your manifest contains:
>   {
>   }
>   ):
>       1: <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %>
>   app/views/currencies/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_currencies_index_html_erb___1553736711_70532840'

the compiled file isn't saving and the packs folder isnt created.
here is a link to the repo on github: https://github.com/omokehinde/cryptoCalculator
please help!

Comment: Do you have the same behavior when you rename hello_react.jsx to hellow_react.js?

Comment: yes i do have the same behavior